# .NET equivalent of curl to upload a file to REST API?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, curl, httpwebrequest

I need to upload an ics file to a REST API. The only example given is a curl command.

The command used to upload the file using curl looks like this:

```
curl --user {username}:{password} --upload-file /tmp/myappointments.ics http://localhost:7070/home/john.doe/calendar?fmt=ics
```

How can I do this using a HttpWebRequest in C# ?

Also note that I may only have the ics as a string (not the actual file).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360832/using-net-to-post-a-file-to-server-httpwebrequest-or-webclient looks to be doing something similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get a working solution. The quirk was to set the method on the request to PUT instead of POST. Here is an example of the code I used:

```
var strICS = "text file content";

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (strICS);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("http://someurl.com");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username", "password");;
request.Method = "PUT";
request.ContentType = "text/calendar";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream ()) {
    stream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
response.Close ();
```