# Load a JSON file from a URL without AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, web-deployment

So I can't seem to find an straight answer to my problem.

What I want to do is load a `JSON` file that's located on a specified URL. It's a **large** complicated `JSON` file. Basically, I've been trying to use `AJAX` to 'get' the file all night long. I've used the `$.getJSON` Jquery shortcut too, without any luck. I believe the server isn't allowing for `AJAX` requests, but if I enter in the URL I can access the file without a problem.

My question is, is there any way I can get the file so I could use it in order to create this little mock up site that I need to create?

Is this possible?

I've tried looking for a way to just rip the text off of the URL and then just turning that into a `JSON` file so I could parse it, but I haven't found any relevant information on this tactic.

If you have any ideas, please let me know, thank you! :D

Comment: If the server doesn't allow CORS or JSONP, you can't get it from the clientside, you would have to use serverside code to get the file, and then write clientside code that executes the serverside script with ajax etc.

Comment: Use curl 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784567/net-equivalent-of-curl-to-upload-a-file-to-rest-api

Comment: What language are you using on your server? See http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Cross-Domain_Proxy.php

Comment: It's not my server. All I have access to is the server side JSON. It's part of a Job application, so all I have to go on is the JSON code they gave me. I may just end up saving the JSON code and using it like that.