# Photo upload with parameters to a PHP page

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, file-upload

I need to upload file the server via .php file, and i've got this information:

> Make a call to the: /uploadFiles.php with these parameters:
>
> - $_POST['user_id']
> - $_FILES['image']

So, my question is what does "call php with parameters $_GET['user_id'] and $_FILES['image']" mean, and how do I make a call to php sucessfully.

I've already, for other needs, succesfully made call to the server via "POST" method, like this:

```
var client = WebClient();
client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

string toSend = "http://example.com/submit.php?userid=10";
client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(toSend), "POST", "");
```

Of course, I did much research before posting, tried a lot of solutions from topics here:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wp7+photo+upload

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update:**

I found out all i need is to simulate this SIMPLE HTML UPLOAD form:

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='http:/myserver.com/upload.php'>
File to upload <input type=file name=image><br>
user_id <input type=text name=user_id><br>
<br>
<input type=submit value=Press> to upload the file!
</form>
```

When i run this in web browser i get good response from upload.php, so i just need the way to simulate this in WP7, i tried everything, i'm desperate.

I used [myToolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http) like this, but same response like when i used webclient, restsharp, hammock:

```
var request = new HttpPostRequest("http://myserver.com/upload.php");
request.Data.Add("user_id", "389096"); // POST data
request.Files.Add(new HttpPostFile("image", "", e.ChosenPhoto, true)); // POST file
Http.Post(request, RequestFinished);
```

Comment: I think you should try to search how to upload a file using WebClient or HttpWebRequest. Some links from SO that may help: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360832/using-net-to-post-a-file-to-server-httpwebrequest-or-webclient) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was sending incorrect FilyType parameter.
I was sending image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png, but when simulating HTML upload form we have to send "image/pjpeg".

I explained it, in details, here (i used RestSharp):
http://nediml.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/uploading-files-to-remote-server-with-multiple-parameters/#more-234

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: Thank God man! I struggled 2 days, till i found this article!