# Photo upload to PHP page C# Stream ReadTimeout

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, timeout, windows-phone-8

I've got the same code as mentioned here: [Photo upload with parameters to a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373250/photo-upload-with-parameters-to-a-php-page)

on a windows phone 8.
My webserver gets the request. Dumping $_FILES gives:

```
Array
(
    [media] => Array
        (
            [name] => pvkeumhbpt.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php4l8jVz
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Image is created and everything is fine, but the size is 0B (black image) and in Debugger I have ReadTimeout of the picture while processing the httpWebrequest.

ideas appreciated ...

Comment: I was able to change the C# Stream to MemoryStream and now I'm getting files with a size. The images are created with given size, but are 'empty'/black!